# How to access methods and attributes in derived property class in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extend the property decorator to my own needs, but I don't know how to access the attributes and methods in the extended property

```
class myproperty(property):
    def __init__(self, tooltip, cls_name,
             fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None, **kwargs ):
        super().__init__(fget=fget, fset=fset, fdel=fdel, doc=doc)
        self._name = ''
        self._value = ''
        self._cls_name = None        # name of GUI object to be used

        self._datatype = None
        self._tooltip = tooltip
        self._cls_name = cls_name
        self._kwargs = dict(**kwargs)

    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._datatype(self._value)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._value = value
        print(f'setting {value}')

    def __call__(self, f):
        self._value = f(self)
        self._datatype= type(self._value )
        self._name = f.__name__
        return self

    def get_membervalues(self):
        return {'name': self._name, 'cls_name': self._cls_name, 'tooltip': self._tooltip}
```

I can use the property:

```
class myclass():
    @myproperty(tooltip='help', cls_name='AnotherClass')
    def data(self): return 4
```

And it seems to work internally

```
a = myclass()
print(a.data)        # prints out 4, __get__() is called
a.data = "10"        #  __set__ is called correctly
print(a.data)        #  prints out 10 correctly
print(type(a.data))  # prints out "int" which is correct
a.get_memvervalues()  # this does not work
```

How do I access the method "get_memvervalues" or the attributes _name, _tooltip etc?
Ive tried with inspect and to cast it but have not yet succeeded.
Bonus question: When the def **call**(self, f)  function is called I get the function pointer to 'data' in myclass. How do I extract the name of the class from that function pointer?

Comment: That's not a proper way to use descriptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I access the method "get_memvervalues" or the attributes _name, _tooltip etc?

From a class (`myclass`):

```
myclass.__dict__['data']
```

From a class instance (`a`):

```
type(a).__dict__['data']
```

In both, `data` is the attribute name.

For example:

```
a = myclass()
desc = type(a).__dict__['data']

print(desc.get_membervalues())    # {
                                  #     'name': 'data', 
                                  #     'cls_name': 'AnotherClass', 
                                  #     'tooltip': 'help'
                                  # }

print(desc._tooltip)              # help

print(vars(desc))                 # {
                                  #     '_name': 'data',
                                  #     '_value': 4,
                                  #     '_cls_name': 'AnotherClass', 
                                  #     '_datatype': <class 'int'>, 
                                  #     '_tooltip': 'help', 
                                  #     '_kwargs': {}
                                  # }
```

But, at first glance, there's a problem with your implementation:

```
a = myclass()
b = myclass()

print("Before:")        # Before:
print("a:", a.data)     # a: 4
print("b:", b.data)     # b: 4

a.data = 10

print("After:")         # After:
print("a:", a.data)     # a: 10
print("b:", b.data)     # b: 10   (!!!)
```

If this makes sense to you, then you can stop reading and you're using the method descriptor in a unconventional way.

Despite there being two class instances, there is only one descriptor instance:

```
type(a).__dict__['data'] is type(b).__dict__['data']
```

(which should be evident as `type(a) is type(b)`).

To support the descriptor "acting differently", the first argument (you call it `instance` in `__set__`, but it's also passed to `__get__`) is a reference to the class instance -- that is what `self` would be inside a traditional method.

You usually want to use this somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about one descriptor instance

Answer (score 1):

`get_membervalues` isn't defined inside `myclass`, so `a` won't have access to it.

It's defined inside `myproperty`, so the next logical conclusion is to try and get to the `myproperty` object associated with `a.data`. Since Python stores the functions in `myclass` in `myclass.__dict__`, we can find the property object like so:

```
a.__class__.__dict__['data']
```

And then call the function from there:

```
a.__class__.__dict__['data'].get_membervalues()
>>> {'name': 'data', 'cls_name': 'AnotherClass', 'tooltip': 'help'}
```